# OpenCV installation failure on windows

Tags: python, opencv, installation

Hi I am trying to install opencv on windows. I am using python version 3.7.3. I have tried the installation tutorials using pip, conda and also followed steps outlined in the documentation:https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-windows/. But no success. I am getting the same error regardless of the approach.

```
Fetching package metadata ...
    CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/a
    naconda/win-64/repodata.json>
    Elapsed: -

    An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
    HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

```
SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'tls_process_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')])")))'))
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements dlib(from versions:none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for dlib

any suggestions on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Conda installer can't verify SSL certificate.

As a workaround you can use a common way of installing Python packages using `pip` in OS terminal if you already have Python and pip installed.

> Packages for standard desktop environments (Windows, macOS, almost any GNU/Linux distribution)
>
> - run `pip install opencv-python` if you need only main modules
> - run `pip install opencv-contrib-python` if you need both main and contrib
>     modules (check extra modules listing from OpenCV documentation)

Answer (score 1):

After trying number of solutions seen online, I was able to resolve the issue. 
`conda install opencv` worked for me. If anyone gets the same issue, refer to this document for reference. It worked for me and hopefully it works for you as well. The link to the document is: http://mathalope.co.uk/2015/05/07/opencv-python-how-to-install-opencv-python-package-to-anaconda-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Its seems your network is not allowing you to access data from command line, we often see these types of issues when we are using office closed network.

In most cases when we disconnect our machines from office network (or take help from IT team to by pass closed network), pip install starts working.

Can you check if running " pip install pandas" also gives you same error, if so then its definitely network issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  "pip install pandas" works fine.

Comment: @Param Its an issue with package requirement file that you are running, the version mentioned in that file is not compatible with you windows,  Please run command " pip install dlib"  without any version. You might have to do same for all packages for which you will see similar error.